# Cordova Android 6.2.1 + Crosswalk 23 => SSL error: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: android, cordova, ssl, crosswalk

I'm trying to make XmlHttpRequest to a REST API exposed through https with a certificate signed by [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificate-compatibility/).

On Android, those requests fail and I get a `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` error.

It seems it fails both with and without Crosswalk.

I've tried to comment the `onReceivedSslError` code in both `org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebViewClient` and `org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkCordovaResourceClient` but it still fails with the same error :(.

Is it the CA that is not recognized? How can I fix this?

Comment: did you found any solution for that? even i too had the same issue.

Comment: yes, as per my reply below, it was just my Android tab date and time settings that needed to be reset.

Answer (score 0):

OK the problem was just that my Android device had a wrong date and time setting ...